# High-order elements of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ have no real eigenvalues

Tags: group-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, modular-forms

Let $\gamma=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{pmatrix} \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$,  $k$ the order of $\gamma$, i.e. $\gamma^k=1$ and $k=\min\{ l : \gamma^l = 1 \}$. I have to show that $\gamma$ has no real eigenvalues if $k>2$.

The eigenvalues of $\gamma$ are
$\gamma_{1,2} = \frac{1}{2} (a+d \pm \sqrt{(a+d)^2-4})$, i.e. I have to show that $(a+d)^2<4$ for $k>2$.

How can I prove this? I have determined the first powers of $\gamma$ to get the condition directly from $\gamma^k = 1$ but I failed. Probably, there is an easier way?

Comment: Hint: finite-order matrices are diagonalizable over $\Bbb{C}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume there is a real eigenvalue.
Then the minimal polynomial of $\gamma$ is a divisor of $X^k-1$ and has degree at most $2$ and has at least one real root. If its degree is $2$, the other root must also be real.
The only real roots of unity are $\pm1$, so the minimal polynomial os one of $X-1$, $X+1$ or $(X-1)(X+1)=X^2-1$.
All three are divisors of $X^2-1$, i.e. we find $\gamma^2=1$.

Comment: This same argument can be used to show that $k=1,2,4,6$. I did that on another question recently, but I can't seem to find it. Basically, $\phi(k)=1,2$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: If by "the same argument" you mean one that also does not use $\gamma\in SL_2(\Bbb Z)$, then I don't see how you could conclude $k\in\{1,2,3,4,6\}$ (supposing that is what you meant to say).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Since the minimal polynomial, of degree $1$ or $2$, must divide $x^k-1$ and no smaller $k$, that means either that it must either be a factor of $x^2-1$ or it must be a cyclotomic of degree $\phi(k)$.  So $k=1,2,3,4,6$. And I did mean to allow $k=3$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Basically, the polynomial $X^2-(a+d)X+(ad-bc)$ has to be a divisor of $X^k-1$ or the square of a divisor of $X^k-1$. If this polynomial is prime over $\mathbb Q$, then the fact that it divides $X^k-1$ and no other $X^d-1$ with $d<k$ means that $X^2-(a+d)X+(ad-bc)$ must be the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_k(X)$ of degree $\phi(k)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I see. Then you are using (I think) that the minimal polynomial of a matrix with rational coefficients (which is where $\gamma\in SL_2(\Bbb Z)$ is used) is rational, otherwise you don't get down to the cyclotomic case. Seems like a bit more work though than in Hagens answer (or mine).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen You can show it pretty easily in case of $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ since the only minimal polynomials can be linear or the characteristic polynomial.  The general result is perhaps tricker, but the case of $2$ is pretty simple.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: My point was just that you need to use somewhere that it is not $\gamma\in GL_2(\Bbb Z)$, where the conclusion about $k$ is simply not true. This will be my last comment, promised.

Answer (score 0):

In dimension $2$, if there is one real eigenvalue the characteristic polynomial splits (two real eigenvalues, possibly equal). If $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $\gamma$ satisfying $\gamma^k=1$ then $\lambda^k=1$, and with $\lambda\in\Bbb R$ this means $\lambda\in\{-1,+1\}$. Also the minimal polynomial of $\gamma$ divides $X^k-1$ so has no multiple roots; therefore $\gamma$ is diagonalisable and $\gamma^2=1$, so $k\leq2$. That $\gamma\in SL_2(\Bbb Z)$ has nothing to do with it (apart for the dimension $2$).